# Google Script - Sending email from spreadsheet - changing the font size

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function emailprint() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var userEmail = "test123@gmail.com";
  var subject = "Shipping Label" + row; 
  var body =""
  body += "\n\nSend To: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Contact Name")).getValue();
  body += "\n\nLocation: " + sheet.getRange(row, getColIndexByName("Location")).getValue();
  body += "\n\nFrom: Thisisatest"

  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {name:"TEST"});
}
```

**:// im looking to change the font size of all the text in body to a larger size... cant seem to figure out how.**

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, you are sending the message as as plain text. If you want to send it with HTML design you will need to use the options tag.

See here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Comment: thanks for the info... still a little lost tho on the html bit.. any chance you can show me how that would work?

Answer (score 0):

The following solves this problem:

```
<pre style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 14px;"> your text is here </pre>
```